# Windows Store App: How do I remove permissions tab from Settings

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

In my app, I have added a settings tab like this.

```
internal static class AccountSettings
{

    public static void Initialise()
    {
        SettingsPane settingsPane = SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView();
        settingsPane.CommandsRequested += settingsPane_CommandsRequested;
    }

    private static void settingsPane_CommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        SettingsCommand accountSettings = new SettingsCommand("accSettings", "Account Settings", (uiCommand) =>
        {
            ShowSettingsPanel();
        });

        args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(accountSettings);
    }

    private static void ShowSettingsPanel()
    {
        var flyout = new SettingsFlyout();
        flyout.Title = "Account Settings";
        flyout.Content = new AccountSettingsPage();
        flyout.Show();
    }
}
```

and I am calling

```
 AccountSettings.Initialise()
```

from App.xaml.cs

It adds this tab in the setting but by default there is one Permissions tab already added which shows the app permissions. How can I remove this permissions tab?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot remove Permission from Settings flyout. You can only add your custom commands to it.

Comment: Can I atleast change the position of it? I see some app having Rate and Review tab which comes after Permissions. How do I get that?

Comment: No, i don't think so.

Comment: Permissions appears any time you have capabilities in your manifest that are user-controllable, like geolocation, microphone, and webcam. Permissions is where the user can turn those on or off. Rate & Review will appear once an app is published in the Store. It won't appear for apps in development or side-loaded apps that weren't acquired from the Store.